# How to run Windows OpenSSH Server interactively?

Tags: windows-10, openssh, interactive

As known OpenSSH Server on Windows 10 (`sshd.exe`) run as a service by default.
But there are cases that require to run OpenSHH Server in an interactive Windows session, not in session 0 by default. For example, let's assume you connect to Windows from some Linux/Android and you don't want to use Desktop connections like VNC and others. And then it's impossible to run the command such `rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation` via SSH successfully as *LockWorkStation* function requires Desktop session i.e. session 1, session 2, etc. And

Sometime ago I found a [post](https://superuser.com/a/1297214/1149277.) stated that it's possible to run SHH Server on Windows interactively but no specific instructions were given then:

> You can run the SSH server in an interactive Windows session, instead
>   as a service. It has its limitations though.

Now I'm looking for those one.

I tried to run `sshd.exe` directly through `cmd` with configuration file and log like

`c:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\sshd.exe -f c:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\sshd_config_default -E log.txt`

but launched this way server doesn't support any incoming connection. The log file contains very little information:

```
Accepted password for The_Immortal from ::1 port 28532 ssh2
CreateProcessAsUserW failed error:1314
fork of unprivileged child failed
```

Unfortunately there is no proper help built in `sshd.exe`. It only shows general list of arguments

```
usage: sshd [-46DdeiqTt] [-C connection_spec] [-c host_cert_file]
            [-E log_file] [-f config_file] [-g login_grace_time]
            [-h host_key_file] [-o option] [-p port] [-u len]
```

And I'm frustrating what's necessary from this to finally run `sshd.exe` interactively?

---

**UPD**: I've just found a big [workaround](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1304) similar to my question but it concerns some customized (upgraded) OpenSSH Server. Anyway with `sshd -d` I have the same error as above.

Comment: You are sure this comment about Interactive mode was for OpenSSH Server on Windows, using the Windows Feature, because the version of OpenSSH installed by that feature does not have every feature that regular old OpenSSH Server has.  **There are many features it does not have.**  Can you provide a link to the statement, without context, it's not possible to determine if your understanding of the comment was correct.  Edit your question instead of submitting a comment.

Comment: **Your link does not work.**  It's not even a URL to a website.

Comment: @Ramhound fixed. Well, actually you are right. The author didnt't mean OpenSSH Server exactly. But I decided there is a way to lauch it interactivelly.

Comment: The Windows OpenSSH Server optional feature, as I said, is not a feature-complete port.  Did you look into psexec?

Comment: @Ramhound SSH is my choice as I'm looking for cross-platform solution as I need to send command from Android as well. Till now there is no PsExec port under Android. 
Could you please explain what you mean by "regular old feature-complete OpenSSH Server"? Where can it be found?

Comment: I would ping the author of that question to explain.  I also wouldn't trust a incomplete answer like that to be accurate.

Comment: @Ramhound  I've no idea how to ping the author as haven't found any PM/chat to the specified user. Just will be waiting for him here then...

Answer (score 0):

#### Preamble

What helped me solve this issue is learning that running sshd in "interactive mode" is equivalent to running sshd as a regular user (not root). It's not something I've had to ever do on Linux, but once defined this way it's easier to find help online.

There are three issues with running sshd as an unprivileged user:

1. Can't access ports below 1024.
2. Can't read ssh host keys (located in `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_{ecdsa,ed25519,rsa,dsa}_key{,.pub}`
3. Can't write PID file to `ssh_host_ecdsa_key`

[source](https://www.golinuxcloud.com/run-sshd-as-non-root-user-without-sudo/)

#### Solution

1. Host keys

Open cmd prompt in `%userprofile%\.ssh`

```
ssh-keygen -q -N "" -t dsa -f ./ssh_host_dsa_key
ssh-keygen -q -N "" -t rsa -b 4096 -f ./ssh_host_rsa_key
ssh-keygen -q -N "" -t ecdsa -f ./ssh_host_ecdsa_key
ssh-keygen -q -N "" -t ed25519 -f ./ssh_host_ed25519_key
```

2. Sshd_config

Copy `%programdata%\ssh\sshd_config` to `%userprofile%\ssh`

```ini
Port <BETWEEN-1024-AND-65535>
HostKey C:\Users\<USER>\.ssh\ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey C:\Users\<USER>\.ssh\ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey C:\Users\<USER>\.ssh\ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey C:\Users\<USER>\.ssh\ssh_host_ed25519_key
PidFile C:\Users\<USER>\.ssh\sshd.pid
```

3. Open new port in firewall

`netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Open Port <BETWEEN-1024-AND-65535>" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=<BETWEEN-1024-AND-65535>`

4. Startup batch script

Create `sshd-interactive-mode.bat` in the `Startup`* folder:

```
start "" C:\Users\user\bin\SilentCMD\SilentCMD.exe "C:\Program Files\OpenSSH\sshd.exe" -f C:\Users\user\.ssh\sshd_config
```

[SilentCMD](https://github.com/stbrenner/SilentCMD/releases) spawns it as a background task. Download it and save to =%userprofile%\bin\SilentCMD=
`start ""` prevents cmd prompt from [lingering on the desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14626301) after sshd exits

#### Notes

- I chose to keep everything in user's `.ssh` directory, but you may choose a separate directory.
- Startup folder: `C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

Comment: Why are you giving twice the same answer?

Comment: I've removed the previous one - it originally suggested adding user permissions to the system host keys, which was a wrong approach. I needed to understand the problem better.